# Plug molding rated at 15 amps, for kitchen it should be 20 amps

Tags: wiring

All Legrand plug molding is rated at 15 amps yet kitchen circuits are 20 amp with 12 guage wire.
How do I make this work. Connections inside plug mold need to be "butt type" as there is no room
for wire nuts.

Comment: Can you add  few pictures showing what you're trying to do?

Comment: I would verify the wire size. If it is wired with #12 wire 2 or more receptacles are allowed to be on a 20 amp circuit. I have been asked to install wire mold (same thing) and the inspector was fine with it I believe 1’ was considered 1 outlet and the overhang in the counter could not be more than 6” , I talked him into also installing receptacles in the wall for resale and he was really happy with that when he got his stand up wheel chair.  wiremold of any brand that is listed can be used but remember 2 circuits are required in a kitchen.

Comment: Are you saying the Plugmold uses 15A sockets, or that the Plugmold you have is wired using 14AWG?

Answer (score 2):

The fact of the sockets being 15A (common) instead of 20A (T-neutral) is nothing to worry about.

15A receptacles *are allowed* on 20A circuits, per NEC 210.21, provided there are 2 or more sockets. I mean sockets not receptacles: The common-as-dirt 2-socket receptacle is 2 sockets.

Interestingly, a Wiremold outlet strip counts as 1 *receptacle* even though it has like 20 sockets or something... not relevant to a kitchen, but some places in Code (and for houses in some local Codes) you must provision 180VA per *receptacle* and/or have an 8- or 12-*receptacle* limit per circuit.  So those plug strips are a fun "cheat" to get a bunch of sockets.

This only becomes an issue if you are trying to plug in an appliance that has a sideways neutral... and when's the last time you've seen one of those?

Comment: I thought the 180VA requirement in 220.14(I) didn't apply Dwelling Units in 220.14(J). Is there someplace else that specifies 180VA?

Comment: @NoSparksPlease Well, some localities bring it in... but you're right generally.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Legrand spec sheet](https://legrand.webdamdb.com/directdownload.php?ti=41609851&tok=k8Ol80J1846Z87gH2jF1sgRR) they have lots of variants available, including 12 AWG or 14 AWG, and including alternating receptacles between two circuits. So if you get the right stuff then there is no problem satisfying both the 20 A rule (by using 12 AWG wire and connecting to 20 A breakers) and the 2 circuit rule. Of course, you may have additional circuits elsewhere in the kitchen and use Legrand for just one, etc. - the possibilities are endless. But stick with 12 AWG and you're good.